# Creating pd.Series from given index and values for some of the entries of the index

Tags: python, pandas, series

I need to create a pd.Series from the following index:

```
[2018-01-01, 2018-02-01, 2018-03-01, 2018-04-01, 2018-05-01, 2018-06-01, 2018-07-01, 2018-08-01, 2018-09-01, 2018-10-01, 2018-11-01, 2018-12-01, 2019-01-01]
```

And this other pd.Series:

```
date
2018-02-01    1
2018-03-01    4
2018-05-01    3
2019-01-01    2
```

I need the output pd.Series index to be the given `index`, and the data, to be the values in the previously shown series, in case the date of the index matches, and 0 otherwise.

The output pd.Series in this case would be:

```
date
2018-01-01      0
2018-02-01      1
2018-03-01      4
2018-04-01      0
2018-05-01      3
2018-06-01      0
2018-07-01      0
2018-08-01      0
2018-09-01      0
2018-10-01      0
2018-11-01      0
2018-12-01      0
2019-01-01      2
```

Any help on this issue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: What did you try ?

Comment: I have no clue how to start.

Comment: Try [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

Comment: Merge what? I have a datetime index and a pd.Series.

Answer (score 2):

I'll create an executable sample dataset from your question:

```
index = ['2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-01', '2018-04-01', 
         '2018-05-01', '2018-06-01', '2018-07-01', '2018-08-01', 
         '2018-09-01', '2018-10-01', '2018-11-01', '2018-12-01', '2019-01-01']
ser = pd.Series(data=[1, 4, 3, 2], 
                index=['2018-02-01', '2018-03-01', '2018-05-01', '2019-01-01'])
```

Now you just have to reindex your series with your desired index and set the fill value to zero:

```
new_ser = ser.reindex(index, fill_value=0)
```

Which will yield your desired output:

```
2018-01-01    0
2018-02-01    1
2018-03-01    4
2018-04-01    0
2018-05-01    3
2018-06-01    0
2018-07-01    0
2018-08-01    0
2018-09-01    0
2018-10-01    0
2018-11-01    0
2018-12-01    0
2019-01-01    2
```